# how to link a href tag from one html file to iframe tag in next html page

Tags: javascript, html

what i am trying to do is,

1. I have a html page lets say **movieslist.html**, it has a list of few movies (all are href links `<a href="movie.html">`
2. Clicking on any movie will redirect me to **movie.html**. Here I am using `iframe` tag to display and play a video from my google drive.

Problem is that I am not getting how to link them both, for example if I give 2 `iframe` tag with drive link as `src` value both are getting display. I want only the movie which I have clicked to be displayed.
how to give this condition or any suggestions on this?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to propagate your movie link from movies.html to movie.html.

**movies.html**

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <a href="movie.html?movieLink=https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oezcBrXr8b-ATkIGD1I9ZQakPP9VX_5W/preview">Movie 1</a>
        <a href="movie.html?movieLink=https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oezcBrXr8b-ATkIGD1I9ZQakPP9VX_5W/preview">Movie 2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**movie.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script>
        function bindUrlWithIFrame(){
            var movieLink = window.location.href.split("?movieLink=")[1];
            var iframeElement = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframeElement.src = movieLink;
            iframeElement.width = 1100;
            iframeElement.height = 500;
            document.body.appendChild(iframeElement);   
        }
        bindUrlWithIFrame();
    </script>
</html>
```

Firstly in movies.html send your movie link in href (hypertext reference) with parameter movieLink.
Second in movie.html retrieve your movie link from URL bar and split by movieLink to get your actual movie link, then dynamically create your iframe element, pass the movie link to it as source, finally adding your iframe element to DOM will work. Upvote for the same, Thanks.

Comment: yes, i have used the same line. But the thing is if it's one movie then it's working fine, what i need is if i click on one movie in movieslist.html it should take me to movie.html page and play that respective movie.
So it's like i have to give many iframe tag same line which you mentioned, but href link from previous page should pick up respective iframe tag and play the movie clicked

Comment: You just have to pass the movie link from href to movie.html page and pass it to iframe src, then it will play your movie. for storing a movie link you can use browser cookies and then retrieve link from it to pass it to iframe.

Comment: i can say i understood a bit but if you can provide me the lines of code it would be very helpful Aman. 
Thanks is advance

Comment: I have edited the answer, just check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I may sound bit dumb but <iframe src=""> what should I give as src value here

Comment: You dont have to, it will be done automatically by the script, just integrate this code, you will get your work done.

Comment: I can share my code base, if you to know how it worked.

Comment: I tried just by integrating the code. But it didn't work.
yes please share your code base so that it will be easy for me to understand

Comment: Just provide your hyperlinks for the movies, I will merge them with my code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oezcBrXr8b-ATkIGD1I9ZQakPP9VX_5W/preview

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-uzNSnZLsh0y53Ss3FxhM1NkIl_WNYAr/preview

these are two movie links

Comment: Edited the code with your movie links, just check and let me know and Upvote me for the same

Comment: Logic is working but video frame is coming at the end of the page. what style attribute can be used to place it where i want?

Comment: you just asked for your iframe not working but if you want to apply the style you can use margin and width height, Now please upvote me for my answer.

Comment: I did, but it says vote will be recorded but not publicly visible due to less points something

Comment: Hi, small doubt.
var movieLink = window.location.href.split("?movieLink=")[1];
what does [1] mean in the above line?

Comment: whenever we split a string with a single comma, it gets separated into two parts and by [1] using this I am accessing the second part.